# table of polygon centroids

Tags: qgis, geoprocessing, polygon, centroids

Given a polygon layer, census tracts, how can I generate a table of centroid coordinates in QGIS, or add columns with the centroid coordinates or generate a new layer of polygon centroid points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are working with 1.8, there is an option that produces a point shape file at

vector/geometry tools/polygon centroids.

Hope it helps

Comment: Yes, you are right, its right there in front of me. Its in 1.7.3 as well. Thanks!